# Using for loop as a filter for a list which contains str and int in python

Tags: python

I am trying to separate a list number by the condition I design
following is a part of my list(loss2)

```
['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 0.0, 0, 0, -0.01074774310660863, -0.007915433104640738, -0.011716167603768606, -0.008357636071380443, -0.007245495610030144, -0.022227332123171357, -0.012516554973567445, -0.007623579146592598, 0.0192778383350173, 0.0192778383350173, -0.015671673141255126, -0.018709607522757046, -0.008574315525083002, -0.0090231515363237,'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 0.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.0065720712926111025, -0.006601488146738127, -0.0016092749610659598, -0.01626232912268551, -0.01218549922131858, -0.007612043606160197, -0.007612043606160197, -0.00501643883024741, -0.003287766049489531, 0.013156255407509906, 0.013156255407509906, 0.01751514102]
```

and I was using for loop to do so.

```
b=0
trail2 = []
for i in loss2:
    if b != 'x':
        if i > 0 and i > b:
            b = i
            trail2.append(b)
        elif i > 0 and i < b and (b - i) < 0.03:
            trail2.append(b)
        elif i > 0 and i < b and (b -i) > 0.03:
            b = 'x'
            trail2.append(b)
        elif i == b:
            trail2.append(b)
        elif i < 0 and b < 0 and i < -0.03:
            b = 'x'
            trail2.append(b)
        elif i < 0 and i > -0.03 and (b - i) < 0.03:
            a = i
            trail2.append(b)
    elif b == 'x':
        if i != 0:
            trail2.append(b)
        elif i == 0:
            b = i
            trail2.append(b)
    else:
        b = 0
        trail2.append(b)
```

but python told me like this

```
---> 51         if i > 0 and i > b:
     52             b = i
     53             trail2.append(b)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

I thought I have avoided this situation by using " if b != 'x' "
so maybe I overlooked something I should notice?
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I think there are functions like `.isdigit()` or something similar that You can use to check whether a variable is a string or digit, also You could try using `try/except`

Comment: what exactly are You trying to do? seperate numbers from strings in a list and put them in different lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using
`if b != 'x':`
when it should be
`if i != 'x':`
Same with the
`if b == 'x':`

Comment: A classic example of why meaningful variable names are essential

Comment: @SiHa Yes, that's a good point! :) And a few comments to describe the variables would also make it more understandable.

Comment: Honestly, if the variables are properly named, you shouldn't need comments for them. Proper names are a large step towards self-documenting code.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand what my problem is :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply different action based on type of input then you might harness [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) from built-in module functools. Simple example: lets get lengths of all elements, where length for str is number of characters and for int it is number of bits required to write it.

```
import functools
@functools.singledispatch
def length(arg):
    return None
@length.register(int)
def _(arg):
    return arg.bit_length()
@length.register(str)
def _(arg):
    return len(arg)
data = ["Hello", 1, "World", 255]
print([length(i) for i in data])
```

output

```
[5, 1, 5, 8]
```

If you want to know more about singledispatch read [PEP 443](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0443/)